# emailing a page that already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm looking at this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html and I get why it would send the html page that is in the view. However how do I send a page that already exists before I created the mailer? I don't want to copy the html and the ruby code over because I don't want another copy of that code to have to maintain.

The page I want to email is an announcements page and there is already another view for the announcements page since it is accessible from other parts of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass :template_path and :template_name hash keys to the specific method in your mailer as in:

```
mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Subject",
         :template_path => 'announcements',
         :template_name => 'index')
```

In this case it will look for templates at app/views/announcements with name index.